# Linear sum of shifted numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy

Given a (m,n) numpy array A, I would like to construct the (m-1,n-1) numpy array B such that B[i,j] equals

```
A[i+1,j+1]+A[i,j]-A[i+1,j]-A[i,j+1]
```

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific case you can use `np.diff` twice:

```
B = np.diff(np.diff(A, axis=0), axis=1)
```

OR

(probably slower but more general) use linear convolution:

```
from scipy import signal
B = signal.convolve(A, ((1, -1), (-1, 1)), mode='valid')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
B = A[:-1, :-1] + A[1:, 1:] - A[1:, :-1] - A[:-1, 1:]
```

For example,

```
In [37]: A = np.arange(24).reshape((6,4))

In [38]: A
Out[38]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])

In [39]: B = A[:-1, :-1] + A[1:, 1:] - A[1:, :-1] - A[:-1, 1:]

In [40]: B
Out[40]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

This avoids loops by taking advantage of the fact that NumPy array arithmetic is performed *element-wise*. So instead of defining `B[i,j]` in a loop, you express the entire calculation as a sum of array slices.